# IIS Basic Authorization ala .htaccess/.htpasswd in apache

Tags: iis, .htaccess, authentication, http-basic-authentication, htpasswd

How do I implement the protection of the pages (asp.net mvc app), so when I hit the home page or any other pages within the application I get a login dialog popup in the browser

I'm looking for something similar to what Apache `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` is doing.

I have IIS 7.5/Windows Server 2008 R2 Web edition.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need to enable Basic Authentication. You can find this setting in the Authentication feature for the site in IIS Manager:

[image]

Double click on the icon then right click on *Basic Authentication* and select *Enable*:

[image]

You can also configure this directly in your `web.config` file (your application doesn't even have to be an ASP.NET application):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <basicAuthentication enabled="true" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
<configuration>
```

This will only work in the `web.config` provided that this feature has been delegated as *Read/Write*.

Out of the box you would need to create a separate Windows 2008 account for each login.

If you wanted to use a custom store (SQL Server, Membership Service) then you'd need to write your own Basic Authentication module:

> [Developing a Module Using .NET](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/170/developing-a-module-using-net/)

Answer (score 2):

In the IIS Manager in Sites->Yoursite->Authentication you can disable "Anonymous Authentication" and enable "Basic Authentication" or any HTTP 401 Challenge that's appropriate for your website.