# How can I password protect an IIS directory with only FTP access?

Tags: authentication, web.config, password-protected

How can I password protect an IIS directory when I only have FTP access to the server? I can't adjust any IIS settings or add users or anything like that.

The answer to:

[IIS Basic Authorization ala .htaccess/.htpasswd in apache](https://serverfault.com/questions/272290/iis-basic-authorization-ala-htaccess-htpasswd-in-apache)

does not help as I only have access to the server via FTP. I just need to password protect a directory.

I've tried several variations of a web.config file. I can get a basic HTTP auth form to pop up when a user attempts to load a page from my test directory, but I can't configure the authentication part. The server complains that:

> Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level. This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

whenever I add an `<authentication>` section to my web.config.

I'm grateful for any help anyone can offer.

Edit: I don't know what version of IIS is running on this server, but here is the server tag from error messages:

> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:1.1.4322.2490;
>   ASP.NET Version:1.1.4322.2494